# Как создать объект внутри другого объекта в UNITY

Tags: unity3d

Мне просто нужно создать создать объект внутри другого объекта с помощью скрипта

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В каком смысле 'внутри'?

Answer (score 1):

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
go.transform.SetParent(parentTransform, false);
```

где `parentTransform` это `Transform` от родитеского объекта. Он может быть получен, например из свйоства

```
public Transform parentTransform;
```

да будет вставлен этот самый родительский объект. Или любым другим способом

---

Доки:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Instantiate(prefab, transform);
```

С этой командой можно создать объект у себя как ребенка и все)